# New to scripting in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: bash, scripts

Hey folks pretty newbish here and trying to do some more advanced things but a little lost.

Here is my script, my goal was to make it an executable however it does not complete the whole of the command it stops short.
Script file info:

```
freeup_boot_space.sh -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root
```

Here's the script itself:

```
dpkg -l linux-{image,headers}-"[0-9]*" | awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v -e `uname -r | cut -f1,2 -d"-"` | grep -e '[0-9]' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

If I execute the above long command at the prompt it works just fine.

However when I try to `sudo ./freeup_boot_space.sh`, it stops short and looks like it doesn't understand the `|` pipes.

Comment: You should be careful with a line like that as you might remove a good working backup kernel that you should have.  Doesn't `sudo apt autoremove` work in removing the older unneeded kernels?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it stops short'? If you have executed this line manually once, there isn't anything to do in the second run since the `grep -v` hasn't anything left.

Comment: Did you confirm that you can run the command manually, in the terminal? If it doesn't run there, then it may not run in the script. Also, have you tried running as sudo?

Comment: Yes the commands works properly when ran manually as displayed above, when made into a file it only runs the first command and does not run any thing after "  |  "  the pipes.

Comment: Thank you folks for the inputs, not worried about a lost kernal, these machines are for a few game servers, minecraft, conan exiles, and ark.  Really for learning and fun already have backups running so if the OS goes kaput its all good.  the goal is to keep /boot from filling up.

Answer (score 0):

In your script, the first line should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: I want to thank you for that answer Se6,  Not only did that work I was able to read up on what that does.  here is a little blurb of my readings and was very informative.

The shell is responsible not only for drawing your little prompt, but interpreting your commands, especially if you put in complicated logic like pipes, conditionals and so on.

bash is the most common shell used as a default shell for users of Linux systems. It is a spiritual descendent of other shells used throughout Unix history.

Comment: If the answer suits you, then please upvote it. (The up arrow...)